# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is a local ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This question was part of my commutative algebra assignment and I was unable to  solve it.

> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is a local ring and find what is it's maximal ideal.

Well , I know the definitions but I am unable to decide how I can find a ideal which is maximal and then prove that this is the only maximal ideal.

Can you please help?

I am taking an course of my university and trying exercises based on that.

Comment: the ideal $(3)$ is maximal and $(9)=(3)^2$. In any ring $A$, if $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$ is a maximal ideal it follows $A/\mathfrak{m}^k$is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^k$: If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{m}^k$ it follows $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: There are literally only three ideals in $\mathbb Z_9.$ You should be able to list them.

Comment: Since, in this ring, $$1=2\cdot 5=4\cdot 7=8\cdot 8,$$ if any of $1,2,4,5,7,8$ is in an ideal, the ideal is the entire ring. Other ideals have to be subsets of $\{0,3,6\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that the ideals of $R/J$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the ideals of $R$ containing $J$.

In this case, we want to find the ideals which contain $(9) \subset \mathbb{Z}$. The only such ideals are $\{(1), (3), (9)\}$. In $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ these correspond to $\{(1), (3), (0)\}$ so that the unique maximal ideal is $(3)$. Hence $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is local.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:** Another approach is the following: The ideal $(3)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is maximal and $(9)=(3)^2$ is the square of $(3)$. In any ring $A$, if $m⊆A$ is a maximal ideal it follows $A/m^k$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $m/m^k$: If $\overline{p} \subseteq A/m^k$ is a prime ideal, it follows $\overline{p}$ corresponds to a prime ideal $p \subseteq A$ containing $m^k$. From this it follows $p=m$: There is an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow m/m^k \rightarrow A/m^k \rightarrow A/m \rightarrow 0$$

and since $A/m$ is a field it follows $m/m^k$ is a maximal ideal - it is by the above argument the only maximal ideal in $A/m^k$